# Crear arreglo en angular

Tags: angular

Quiero crear una lista en angular 6 pero obtengo error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at DatasComponent.<anonymous> (datas.component.ts:23)
```

este es mi codigo :

```
export class DatasComponent implements OnInit {
  private listUsers: object[];

  constructor(private datasService: DatasService) {
    console.log(this.datasService);
  }

  async ngOnInit() {

    this.listUsers.push(await this.datasService.getUsers());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambie la declaracion a   `private listUsers: any[] = [];` y se soluciono el problema